# Get Query Result from SQL Server with VBA without CopyFromRecordSet

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I have the following VBA query from SQL-Server, returning just one result. My question is how to read it. So far I have found one way to do it, but I do not want to use it.

```
Dim rsData              As Object
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

With rsData
    .ActiveConnection = cnLogs
    .Open "USE DB SELECT [VersionNumber] FROM Main WHERE [IsLastCurrent] = 1"
End With
```

Solution I do not want to use:

```
Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know why you don't want to use `CopyFromRecordset`

Comment: Because with CopyFromRecordset I should write it on the table somewhere, and I just want to take the value and assign a variable to it.

Comment: `myVar=rsData.Fields("VersionNumber")` you also need to ensure there is data in rsData first

Comment: This returns error 3265... Any ideas?

Comment: See my edit. It may be an error en SQL statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the values in a `Recordset` record by record using the `Fields` property.  When you first open a recordset, it is either empty (in which case `recordset.BOF` and `recordset.EOF` are both true) or it points to the first record in the set (in which case `recordset.BOF` and `recordset.EOF` are both false).  You then access the data in that record using (for example):

```
rsData.Fields("VersionNumber").Value
```

and you can move through the records (if you have more than one) using the `MoveFirst`, `MoveLast`, `MoveNext`, and `MovePrevious` methods of the `recordset` object.

Comment: >Debug.Print rsData.Fields("VersionNumber").Value< this returns 3265 error. Any idea why? My query works in SQL-Server, returning the exactly correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this change in SQL command:

```
With rsData
    .ActiveConnection = cnLogs
    .Open "USE DB; SELECT [VersionNumber] FROM Main WHERE [IsLastCurrent] = 1;"
End With

If (rsData.EOF = False) OR (rsData.BOF = False) Then
 'there are recordset
 myVar=   rsData.Fields(0).value
End If

rsData.Close
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the problem was at the serverrole of the user. I was having only public and due to some reason it did not want to copy all the fields. I have added more priviliges and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the data in memory, use an array variable like
Dim `rsArray` as variant and then copy the record set to it with:

```
rsArray = rsData.GetRows
```